# Which Shell object is the correct one constructing a JFace dialog

Tags: java, dialog, jface

I'm new in JFace and I'm testing some of its components.
Now I'm a little bit confusing about the different methods to show a modal window.
For example I have an application with a button and want to open a dialog by clicking this button:

```
public class TestApp extends ApplicationWindow {
  protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    Button button1 = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    button1.setText("Open");
    button1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(...);
        myDialog.open();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And now it's the question which Shell object I have to assign to the Dialog constructor.
For that I found the following alternatives:

```
new MyDialog(getShell());
new MyDialog(parent.getShell());
new MyDialog(new Shell());
```

But which one is the correct or the most common? And where are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the shell of the current dialog / window so:

```
new MyDialog(getShell());
```

is what you normally use.

This makes the new dialog a child of the current window. So if you close the window the dialog will close as well.